# Why is my imported object transparent when rendered?

Tags: rendering, transparency

I imported a roblox mesh to blender, it looks fine when it's in viewport shading mode:

[image]

It looks like this:

[image]

But when it's in rendered viewport mode it looks like this:

[image]

It's like it's transparent. I want the bowtie, sword and face not transparent.

Comment: Hard to see where the problem is. Normally I'd say it comes from the materials on the objects, so it would be interesting to see the material setups.

Comment: eevee? Cycles? How did you create the materials. Edit your question and show the controls for the materials.

Answer (score 0):

Check your materials and see if there's any alpha values applied on the objects. It does look like it comes from the materials